# Cannot convert 'const bool' to 'jobject

Tags: c++, hashmap, java-native-interface

I need to add a `bool` to an `object map`, my `bool` is defined as a primitive, and I need to convert it to an object.

How do I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? How doesn't it work? Can you please show the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: my signature is as follows : put(JNIEnv* env, jobject map, jobject key, jobject value)
but i am trying to put a primitive, i am new to c++ so i am not sure of the syntax to cast or convert my primitive to an object

Comment: @Lena Could you please include the code in the question according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your bool to a jboolean then box the jboolean into a Boolean jobject with JNI calls like this:

```
jboolean value = true;

jclass booleanClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Boolean");
jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(booleanClass, "<init>", "(Z)V", false);
jobject booleanObject = env->NewObject(booleanClass, methodID, value);
```

Comment: B? not Z?      this is just text to make the comment longer although it is absolutely not needed and needs to be ignored